# where i should get USA water historical data for data science in python?

Tags: data-request

I am searching for particulate domain name they provide water data so I can scroll all data for my application.For weather i am using wunderground.

Comment: i need data for screen scraping or in json formate

Comment: Do you mean "a particular domain name"? "Particulates" are small particles. What kind of water data? River flow? Water quality? Rainfall? What time span? The whole USA? Have you tried this google thing?

Comment: yes i try to google it. i need for  water quantity in river or reservoir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usgs water has some historic, and real-time water data
http://www.usgs.gov/water/